# How to get all the information of the item from the ion select?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, ion-select

I load a list of items from the `Firestore` and put them in the ion select, the problem is that as each item has an id I need to get the id of the selection.

**This is my code to get the items in the controller.**

```
this.MesasColeccion = this.mesasser.getMesaListfromFirestore();
this.MesasColeccion.snapshotChanges().subscribe(mesasLista => {
  this.mesas  = mesasLista.map(mesa => {
    return {
      nombre: mesa.payload.doc.data().nombre,
      capacidad: mesa.payload.doc.data().capacidad,
      estado: mesa.payload.doc.data().estado,
      union:mesa.payload.doc.data().union,
      id: mesa.payload.doc.id
    }
  });

  this.mesas2  = mesasLista.map(mesa2 => {
    return {
      nombre: mesa2.payload.doc.data().nombre,
      capacidad: mesa2.payload.doc.data().capacidad,
      estado: mesa2.payload.doc.data().estado,
      union:mesa2.payload.doc.data().union,
      id: mesa2.payload.doc.id
    }
  });
});
this.MesasObservable = this.MesasColeccion.valueChanges();
```

**This is the code to show the list in the ion-select:**

```
<ion-card>
<ion-card-content>
  <ion-item id="mesas-select1">
  <ion-label >
    Mesa #1:
  </ion-label>
  <ion-select  [(ngModel)]='Gruposobj.nombrem1' name="Mesa#1" placeholder="Selecciona la mesa"  >
    <ion-option   *ngFor="let mesa of mesas">
      {{mesa.nombre}}
    </ion-option>
  </ion-select>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item id="mesas-select1">
    <ion-label >
      Mesa #2:
    </ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]='Grupos2obj.nombrem2' name="Mesa#2" placeholder="Selecciona la mesa" >
      <ion-option *ngFor="let mesa2 of mesas2" >
        {{mesa2.nombre}}
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

The `ngmodel` assigns the selected option to the attribute in the GruposModel. In this case the object of vinculacionmodel is Gruposobj and Grupos2obj. When the user selects an item of ionic-select, I need to get the id selected from an item. Because I will assign this mesa.id && mesa2.id to the vinculacionmodel with Gruposobj.mesa1 && Gruposobj.mesa2.

This is the vinculacionmodel:

```
export interface vinculacionmodel {
    
    id?:string;
    mesa1:string;
    mesa2:string;
    mesa3:string;
    nombrem1:string;
    nombrem2:string;
    nombrem3:string;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want ID from the object you can implement `ionChange` event on your `ion-select` and will get the selected object.

**Please refer to the below code for more detail.**

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]='Grupos2obj.nombrem2' name="Mesa#2" placeholder="Selecciona la mesa" (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
<ion-option *ngFor="let mesa2 of mesas2" [value]="mesa2['id']">
    {{mesa2.nombre}}
</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**ionChange event in .ts file:**

```
onSelectChange(selectedValue: any) {
    //Selected Value Id will get as param ==> selectedValue
    //Selected Object
    var item = this.mesas2.find(item => item['id'] === selectedValue);
    //Position of object in array
    var postion = this.mesas2.findIndex(item => item['id'] === selectedValue);
}
```

Hope this will help you to get your ID from `ios-select`.

Comment: Thanks for your help!, if i need other value with mesa2['capacidad'] in the  ion-option define other value??

Comment: yes you can but at a time you can bind only one value with ion-select.

Comment: but the problem is that i need bind other value, when i print item ("console.log(item)")  the result is a struct with all atributes of mesasmodel, how can i access to the item['capacidad'], thanks

Comment: you can directly access like `item['capacidad']` it will give you provided attribute value.